# Intent for a Skype call using email information in the datas

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I would like to open a **Skype** `Intent` (better with a direct call if possible) using the email of the user.

I find this but it seem it work only with the **Skype** username :

```
Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + "user_name"));            
startActivity(skype);
```

It is possible to `setData` with the email of the **Skype** account? If not, it is possible to get the username thanks to the email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem it's not possible using email address in the Intent, only using username.